# Why is the execution plan of these two equivalent queries so wildy different (inner join + partition by)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Running on SQL Server 2012.

I have two queries that are, as far as I can tell, equivalent one to the other.

Query A:

```sql
select
        t.value_dt
    ,   t.dim_id
    ,   t.my_float
    ,   l = max(my_float) over (partition by t.dim_id order by value_dt)
from tbm.my_fact_table t
inner join tbm.my_dimension b
on t.dim_id = b.dim_id
where b.my_attribute = 'my_filter'
```

Query B:

```
select
        t.*
from (
select
        t.value_dt
    ,   t.dim_id
    ,   t.my_float
    ,   l = max(my_float) over (partition by t.dim_id order by value_dt)
from tbm.my_fact_table t
)t
inner join tbm.my_dimension b
on t.dim_id = b.dim_id
where b.my_attribute = 'my_filter'
```

Here are the relevant indexes :

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [fact_ix] ON [tbm].[my_fact_table]
(
    [dim_id] asc,
    [value_dt] asc
)
INCLUDE ([my_float]) 

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [dim_ix] ON [tbm].[my_dimension]
([my_attribute] ASC)
INCLUDE ([dim_id])
```

The difference: Query A runs in 0 second, Query B takes minutes to run. And of course they yield the same result set. The execution plan sheds some light however: whereas Query A reduces the scope of `tbm.my_fact_table` right off the beginning, Query B waits until the end of the execution plan to filter the result with the filter.

Question: why is SQL Server fooled by such a simple expression. I thought the query was parsed to evaluate it under its simplest expression, and that CTEs and subqueries did not influence the final execution plan.

[image: Execution plan]

I redacted the real names of the tables and indexes, but the two execution plans only use the non clustered indexes indicated above.

Comment: Doing the window function *before* the join is quite different from doing it afterwards.  The results might be the same on your data, but that is not generally the case.  The queries are different, so they have different execution plans.

Comment: Well ok, but is there any way to let sql server know they are equivalent? In my case I would like to expose the subquery as a view so the user can then filter it.

Comment: If you do this as a `VIEW` you may well get another execution plan again. SQL Server is making the best execution plan for the information it has.

Comment: Building execution plans is an amazingly complicated process, there are so many variables to take into account and the optimizer has to be sure the chosen data access and join methods are valid for all allowable data. My *guess* would be it's unable to optimize the second query as it cannot know in advance what would be excluded by the inner join - using `max()` means that value could be excluded so giving incorrect results - so it will not do that.

Comment: @gordon_linoff - In this case the join predicate only includes the column mentioned in the sub-query's PARTITION BY. Thus, the join can exclude a partition, include a partition, or duplicate a partition. In none of those cases would `MAX(x) OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY z)` ever yield different results.  Both queries will always give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in query A, your data is filtered right off the bat with the join and where condition. So aggregation only executes for filtered data.

Whereas in Query B, the aggregation function is executed for every single row in your fact table plus you are returning every single row as subquery.

And that's the bottle neck of second query.

If you look at the data flow pipes in the execution plans, you can see it clearly.
pipes in the second plan are thicker and they go up to where they are filtered by the join.

So in your second query you are telling the SQL engine *Not* to filter data, and it won't. So the only way is to to rewrite it with Query A.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the table definitions, so we can't see what indexes are present.  We can't even see if it's using the same indexes in the two queries.

(Hint: edit your question to include these.)

In absence of that information, my best bet is that you Do Not have an index on `my_fact_table(dim_id, value_dt)`, which would be ideal for your window function.

This means that the optimiser has to choose a non ideal way to solve the window function. The problem there being that one method is great for when your query has just one `dim_id`, but AWFUL when processing the whole fact table.  Then again, a method that's great for processing the whole table would be AWFUL when processing just one `dim_id`.  As your where clause doesn't constrain the `dim_id` directly, the optimiser can't actually tell if the query will be for a small volume of ids, or a large volume, so it has to guess.

If you don't have the compound index mentioned above, create it and try again (though you may need to force a recompile of the plan to make use of the new index).  That way the index can be used for either case, with no need for non-ideal methods or guessing of cardinality, etc.

- Or, even `my_fact_table(dim_id, value_dt) INCLUDE (my_float)` for best results

Also, if your where clause does ALWAYS yield just One `dim_id`, you could try adding a unique constraint to the `my_attribute` column, so the optimiser can "know" that one string value always yields one id.  Or, reform the query to make that explicit...

```
select
    t.*
from (
    select
        t.value_dt
    ,   t.dim_id
    ,   t.my_float
    ,   l = max(my_float) over (partition by t.dim_id order by value_dt)
from tbm.my_fact_table t
)t
WHERE
   t.dim_id = (SELECT dim_id FROM tbm.my_dimension WHERE my_attribute = 'my_filter')
```

Comment: I edited my question. As you can see I precisely use the index you mention! Unfortunately there's no 1-1 relation between the `dim_id` and `my_attribute`.